# I get the following error in mvc4,'System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException' occurred in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

i get the following error in the line

```
Employee employee = employeeContext.Employees.Single(x => x.EmployeeId==id)
```

> An exception of type
>   'System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException' occurred in
>   EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll but was not handled in user code

my controler is

```
public class EmployeeController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /Employee/

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
    public ActionResult Details(int id)
    {
        EmployeeContext employeeContext = new EmployeeContext();
        Employee employee = employeeContext.Employees.Single(x =>x.EmployeeId==id); 

        return View(employee);
    }

}
```

and model class is :

```
[Table("tblEmployee")]
public class Employee
{
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
}
```

context class is :

Comment: There can be many reasons of this error - for example, whether the connection string is correct or not. Also, whether the employee with specific id exists or not. Try verifying connection string, and also use "SingleOrDefault" instead of "Single". You may first need to try to find exact error causing the issue.

Comment: it seem that your employee class is not bind correctly with database table ,  compare table and model class attributes and types.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this by changing

```
Employee employee = employeeContext.Employees.Single(x =>x.EmployeeId==id);
```

into

```
Employee employee = employeeContext.Employees.Where(x =>x.EmployeeId==id).FirstOrDefault;
```

Comment: Why should he do this?

Comment: I think `.FirstOrDefault` is rather a method than a property!

Comment: sorry...i miss that...try employeeContext.Employees.Where(x =>x.EmployeeId==id).FirstOrDefault();